# Sql subquery with a group by and a join on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, aggregate

So i have two tables
EMPLOYEE- Contains columns including EMPLOYEE_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID and SALARY
DEPARTMENTS - Contains columns including DEPARTMENT_NAME, and DEPARTMENT_ID

I need to display the department name and the average slary for each department and order it by the average salaries.

I am new to DBs and am having trouble.
I try to do a subquery in the from field ( this subquery returns exactly what i need minus the department name which requires me to then join the departments table to the results) all the data in the subquery is in one table- employees. while department name is in the departments table.

here is what i tried.

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, T.PERDEPT
  FROM
(
 SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, AVG(SALARY) AS PERDEPT
 FROM EMPLOYEE
 GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
 ORDER BY PERDEPT
) AS TEST T
JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID=T.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

This returns a

> ***SQL command not properly terminated***

on the line with the `AS TEST T`

any and all help is greatly appreciated
many thanks

Comment: the command didnt format correctly, the line breaks did not show up

Comment: just alias table `DEPARTMENTS` as `D`

Comment: Side notes: An `ORDER BY` in a subquery is nothing more than a wish that the optimizer will order your output a certain way.  Put ordering on your top-level query, or get unstable output.  Several answers are pointing out that you don't even need the subquery - for future askers, that's likely true given the (assumed) data model, but subquery aggregation is generally used to solve duplicate row issues.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you ask:

```
select d.department_name, avg(e.salary) as avg_salary
from salary_department d
left join employee e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_name
order by avg(e.salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply correct your table aliases as you seem to have two aliases for subquery (*TEST* and *T*) and no assignment for *D*. Adjust SQL with one alias for each table/query reference:

```
...
(
 SELECT ...
) AS T
JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
```

With that said, you do not even need the subquery as aggregate query with `JOIN` should suffice, assuming *DEPARTMENT_ID* is unique in *DEPARTMENTS* table to not double count the aggregate.

```
SELECT D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
       AVG(E.SALARY) AS PERDEPT
FROM EMPLOYEE E
JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
  ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
         D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
ORDER BY AVG(SALARY)
```